# XSLT to remove element when parent has namespace defined

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<envelopeSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <envelopeId>123</envelopeId>
    <status>sent</status>
    <statusDateTime>2016-06-02</statusDateTime>
    <uri>/envelopes/123</uri>
</envelopeSummary>
```

I'm trying to come up with XSLT that would remove the **uri** element. I have tried the XSLT below, but it does not remove the uri element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uri"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Interestingly enough, it works if I get rid of the namespaces defined in the envelopeSummary element of the original XML. Unfortunately, I cannot modify XML.

Any idea how to remove an element if a parent element has a namespace defined? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to remove an element if a parent element has a namespace defined?

The problem is **not** that the "parent element has a namespace defined". **All** the elements in your XML input are in the default namespace declared at the root element (namespaces are inherited).

To address such element, you must declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when selecting/matching the element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:uri"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this preserves the original namespaces on all the nodes that are passed by the *identity transform* template.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, Thanks a lot for your answer and the explanation! It worked!!! This Monday is not as bad as it seemed an hour ago :) Thanks again.